# Modular document – retrieving file with compilation error

Tags: compiling

I have a question concerning problems that can arise when compiling a modular document (multifile document). If during the compilation I get an error, how do I get the file to which the error belongs?

Thanks in advance for any feedback.

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing this out. I searched but I could not find anything: my fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classic way is to match `(...)` in the log file to see the currently open file, but simpler is to use the commandline option `--file-line-error` so that error messages are prefixed with the filename.